# Probability density in histogram with standard deviation different than 1

Tags: density-function, histogram

I generate a histogram for normal data with standard deviation $\neq 1$.

```
x <- rnorm(1000, mean=0; sd=0.01)
hist(x, freq=FALSE)
```

I also use `freq=FALSE` to see probabilities, but plot looks like Y axis is multiplied by my sd:

[image: histogram]

My question is if `x` should be first normalized to sd=1 before I use `hist` with `freq=FALSE`? In documentation for `hist` I do not see such a requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify `freq=FALSE` area under the histogram represents proportion of the data (i.e. the histogram is a density estimate). The total area is 1.

So the *height* is not estimating probability, the *area* is.

If you make the s.d. smaller, the Y-axis must be larger by the same factor (or the area would no longer be 1). This means that as with any density, the Y-axis is scaled by the inverse of the standard deviation (well, to be more accurate, it's scaled for the bin width, and that is by default related to an estimate of the standard deviation, though it's also a function of the sample size). If at a fixed sample size you halve the standard deviation you should get about the same number of bins for about half the range, so you should have the height approximately double.